# Combining Data from 2 Columns into 1 in a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is a small subset of the data i am working with:

```
+-------------------+----------------+---------+----------+----------+
|               date|       home_team|away_team|home_score|away_score|
+-------------------+----------------+---------+----------+----------+
|1872-11-30 00:00:00|        Scotland|  England|         0|         0|
|1873-03-08 00:00:00|         England| Scotland|         4|         2|
|1874-03-07 00:00:00|        Scotland|  England|         2|         1|
|1875-03-06 00:00:00|         England| Scotland|         2|         2|
|1876-03-04 00:00:00|        Scotland|  England|         3|         0|
|1876-03-25 00:00:00|        Scotland|    Wales|         4|         0|
|1877-03-03 00:00:00|         England| Scotland|         1|         3|
|1877-03-05 00:00:00|           Wales| Scotland|         0|         2|
|1878-03-02 00:00:00|        Scotland|  England|         7|         2|
|1878-03-23 00:00:00|        Scotland|    Wales|         9|         0|
|1879-01-18 00:00:00|         England|    Wales|         2|         1|
|1879-04-05 00:00:00|         England| Scotland|         5|         4|
|1879-04-07 00:00:00|           Wales| Scotland|         0|         3|
|1880-03-13 00:00:00|        Scotland|  England|         5|         4|
|1880-03-15 00:00:00|           Wales|  England|         2|         3|
```

I wish to calculate the total number of matches each team has played.

To do that, I am trying to create a column `all_teams` which should contain all the entries from `home_team` and `away_team`.

I tried:

```
new_df = old_df.withColumn("all_teams", old_df.home_team) \
               .withColumn("all_teams", old_df.away_team)
```

This query ran but did not give me the right output.

Any leads on how to achieve this?

*Note - I am working with Pyspark v2.3*

Answer (score 1):

Use `F.array()`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

old_df.withColumn('all_teams', F.explode(F.array('home_team', 'away_team'))) \
      .groupby('all_teams') \
      .count()              \
      .show()
```